# Tub drain wrench doesn't fit

Tags: drain, bathtub

I am trying to replace my tub drain:
[image]

I tried one of these guys:
[image]

but neither end fits the hole pattern. So then I thought it had to be this one:
[image]

but the "fork" side is too narrow.

It looks like the brass part is slotted for a flathead screwdriver, but it didn't turn easily, and I didn't want to try to crank on it (which is hard with a screwdriver...) until someone tells me that is indeed the way to remove this :). Any suggestions?

------- Edit (update) -----
I got the brass nut off, and the chrome part simply lifted out:

[image]
[image]

Here's what's left:
[image]

It seems like exactly the same thing, just plastic this time! The wrenches still do not fit. I can't tell exactly what's happening past the 'X', but it doesn't look like it goes straight down into a pipe - it seems to start curving almost immediately and has something odd (to an untrained eye) right below the 'X' (see the red circle below):
[image]

There also seems to be some kind of an O-ring between the tub and the plastic "drain" piece below the tub:

[image]

I am starting to think this isn't supposed to be removed... can anyone confirm/deny?

Note, there is no lever to indicate that a built-in popup stopper is present:
[image]

Comment: A socket for the brass nut(guessing 3/4 inch plus),  If those tools don't fit after, a pair of good size needle nose pliers should.

Comment: @crip659 What happens after the cut comes off? Do I still need to unscrew the rest of it? or just pull it straight up somehow?

Comment: Nut quite sure if just the nut holding it.  Might turn/come off when undoing the nut.  Make sure socket is good fit on nut, will round corners with a loose fitting socket.

Comment: If the outside doesn't come up after the nut is off (and it's possible that the nut is integrated with the outside, so everything will come off at once), first try lifting, then try twisting. You can hacksaw/grinder a notch (or a few) in the interior of the ring, and tap tap tap it counterclockwise with a cold chisel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already successfully removed the top part of the drain.  The bottom part is just butt up against that gasket that you highlighted.  It's being held in place by the plumbing.  Your next step is to go underneath the tub, disconnect the plumbing, and remove the drain from underneath.

The other bits that you are pointing out inside the drain pipe appear to be part of a pop up stopper mechanism.  If so you will also need to disconnect that, also from underneath the tub.

**Edit:**

[image]

I've outlined in yellow what I think is a tongue that would lift a popup stopper, and in green what I think is a hinge for it.  *Somewhere* there must be a lever or knob to operate this.  It's probably that big round chrome thing under the bath spout.  Turn it.  The tongue should move up and down.  If it does, you can go find a new stopper like this one:

[image]

although getting one that fits properly may prove very difficult.  If the tongue doesn't move when you turn the knob, give up.  You would need to open the ceiling below to fix it or replace it with a modern popup that is push-on push-off.

Comment: Hm, "underneath the tub" I assume means "cut a hole in the ceiling below the tub? All I wanted to do was put a pop up stopper in - definitely not worth a hole in the ceiling haha. The stopper I have I don't believe is a pop up, but you are saying perhaps it is (and I assume is broken, because it doesn't pop up haha).

Comment: Yes, you said "replace the drain" so yes, whether it's through the ceiling below or some other way, I thought you meant you want to replace the whole thing.  The part that you removed is what squeezes that rubber gasket between the drain and the tub.  Hopefully you can replace it and the gasket will still hold.  You also want plumber's putty underneath it before you put it back.

Comment: Jiggle the lever that operates the popup.  You should see that little metal tab inside the drain moving up and down.  If not, forget about the popup.  If yes, you may be able to just buy a new stopper that will work.  My guess is the lever mechanism broke so the previous owner/user replaced the stopper with a non-popup one that can be lifted from above.

Comment: I think we have a case of "dumb homeowner doesn't know the right terminology". I just wanted to replace the stopper with a popup stopper, not replace the entire drain.

Comment: Go on youtube to see how to assemble a bathtub drain.  Watch a few different videos, then put yours back together.   Ask a new question about replacing a missing popup stopper and show the one you have now and whether the mechanism works, which you can see by looking down the drain as you flip it.

Comment: Ok I'll ask a separate question. I posted a picture here though for completeness and I do not seem to have a lever to operate a popup stopper.

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed - you were absolutely right that the big chrome disk rotates to lift the tongue in the built-in popup stopper (I thought it was an overflow drain!!). Everything was functioning perfectly, it was just a case of a dumb user. Thanks a million! (now let's hope by reseating the gasket I didn't introduce a leak...)

Answer (score 1):

Search `drain extractor`.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drain+extractor&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

I have used the pictured one with great success.

Pictured upside down.

The cam end fits into the drain and a handle for a socket wrench set fits into the other end.

[image]

Comment: See the Updates on the question - I got the chrome piece out but it doesn't seem like I could fit a tool like this into what's left?

Comment: the picture shows that the drain is no longer connected to the tub

Comment: This tool is useful when the other tools above fail to get the job done.   In this case, however, that part of the job is done.  The top half of the drain has been removed.  Next step is to go underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using needle nose pliers: open jaws and insert into the opening, then twist handles.

Use a "tub drain extractor" in the right size.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Superior-1-5-in-Drain-Removal-Wrench/5000204639?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-208-_-plumbingtools-_-5000204639-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAjw_JuGBhBkEiwA1xmbRRQp1t4KBhdghYSf6nrHiO-VW7w9q-3wJ8PBoJiEmpJyN9-3fv0J6hoCpCsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

https://youtu.be/6X7YLmY3o3k

Comment: I got the nut off and removed the chrome piece, but a plastic version of the 'X' remains. I'm not convinced it is intended to be twisted out - see updates to the Question. The "tub drain extractor" would not fit in this as-is (unless I broke the plastic 'X'), but trying to turn it with pliers is making me thing it is not intended to be removed - could that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

It's a hexagon, so try an appropriate size single hex socket. The slot is there for easy fitting when new, and not corroded/covered in clag.

Comment: I got the nut off, but now there's a plastic version of the same thing right below it (no nut this time ha) - see updates to the Question.